# How to evaluate a CSE formula using PhpSpreadsheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, phpspreadsheet

I'm using PhpSpreadsheet (1.15.0) to generate a XLSX document with formulas.
One of this formula is a Ctrl+Shift+Enter (CSE) formula.

When generating a document and then opening it, simple formulas (like '=SUM(A1:A2)') are evaluated. Users have nothing to deal with formulas, they just have to fill the cells.

However, I don't know how to make my CSE formula evaluated when opening. Right now, the formula is valid and correctly translated with localized functions' names, but users still have to evalute it manually by going on the cell, then in the formula bar and finally pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Isn't there any way to tell Excel, through PhpSpreadsheet, to evaluate this formula on opening?

As for example, here is my CSE formula:
`=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(E14:E25="CREDIT_CARD",MATCH(F14:F25,F14:F25,0)),ROW(F14:F25)-ROW(F14)+1)>0))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems PhpSpreadsheet can't do that right now, I don't know why.
There must be some complications about that.

**But I found a pull request that fits my needs**, by handling array formulas: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/pull/1591